# Efficiency in creating a variable in a deferred function

Tags: python-3.x

Consider the two classes below.

```
class Alpha:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def Bar(self, x):
        def Foo(mult):
            return x * mult

        self._Foo = Foo

    def Foo(self, mult):
        return self._Foo(mult)

class Beta:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def Bar(self, x):
        self._x = x

    def Foo(self, mult):
        return self._x * mult
```

For `Alpha` with a deferred function `_Foo`, I believe it is more efficient memory-wise since it only evaluates `x` when the function is called. For `Beta` on the other hand, `x` is stored explicitly as a class attribute.

The question is, where exactly is `x` stored in `Alpha`? How efficient is it compared to `Beta`?

Comment: x is stored explicitly as a class attribute, only when Bar is called!

Comment: you're talking about `Beta` right? If so, yes it surely does. I'm more concerned about `Alpha`. Where's `x` stored?

Answer (score 1):

`x` is not stored in `alpha` as a class attribute, it is only created when you call the function, `Foo`. This eliminates the need unnecessary data storage.

Comment: I see. But in the case where Foo is really called, where is `x` stored then? And is it still more efficient than `Beta`? After `Foo` is done being called, will `x` be garbage collected unlike `Beta` where it persists forever?

Comment: In Beta, it exists as long as the class variable exists in scope. `x` in alpha will be garbage collected after executing once.

Comment: That's interesting. Hmm, so when you execute it a second time, `x` exists temporarily again then gets garbage collected after?  How can one variable keep existing and deleted repeatedly. It must've been stored somewhere right?